# sonata-admin: creating a voter

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am using Symfony 4.4 and sonata-admin 3.107

I created a voter for one of my admin pages (SampleAdmin).

```
class SampleVoter extends Voter
{
   protected function supports($attribute, $subject): bool
    {
        return in_array($attribute, ['LIST', 'VIEW', 'CREATE', 'EDIT'])
            && $subject instanceof 'App\Entity\Sample';
    }
    
    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        if ($attribute === 'EDIT') {
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I registered it in my services:

```
App\Voter\SampleVoter:
   tags: [ security.voter ]
```

But it is not loaded when loading the sonata page in the browser.
Should I do something more?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know not loaded? Raise exception in `supports()` method:

```php
class SampleVoter extends Voter
{
   protected function supports($attribute, $subject): bool
   {
       return in_array($attribute, ['LIST', 'VIEW', 'CREATE', 'EDIT']);
   }
    
   protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        if ($attribute === 'EDIT') {
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

btw, No need to register in services.yaml, because of service auto wiring.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, my mean from `not loaded` is when I go to the intended page in the browser, the `$subject` is null, also `$attribute` is a role, not one of the `LIST`, `VIEW`, `CREATE`, ...

Comment: Do you tried my `throw exception` hack? visit your page, does it fail?

Comment: Yes I tried it, it failed.